# How to give a picture a Sepia filter

Tags: java

I am trying to get a picture to print out with a sepia filter, but it just prints the same (unedited) picture twice. How do I get my sepia code at the bottom to work? The code turns the picture into grayscale, and then sepia.

```
import images.*;

public class Sepia{

 public static void main(String[]args){
  APImage image = new APImage("lobster.jpg");
  image.draw();
  APImage aCopy = image.clone();
  for (Pixel p: aCopy){
     int red = p.getRed();
     int green = p.getGreen();
     int blue = p.getBlue();
     int average = (red + green + blue) / 3;
     p.setRed(average);
     p.setGreen(average);
     p.setBlue(average);

     if (red < 63){
       red = (int)(red *1.1);
       blue = (int)(blue * 0.9);
     }else if (red < 192){
       red = (int)(red*1.15);
       blue = (int)(blue *0.85);
     }else{
       red = Math.min((int)(red*1.08),255);
       blue = (int)(blue *0.93);
     }

     aCopy.draw();
     aCopy.save();
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you kind of thinking that javascript is the big brother of java or something? ;-)

Comment: What is `APImage`? It's not part of the Java standard library. What is Pixel?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I also googled, it's http://home.wlu.edu/~lambertk/hsjava/edition4/whatsnew/imagedocs/images/apimage.html (some awkrward piece of code, IMHO...)

Answer (score 0):

Try and add this before the draw.

```
 p.setRed(red);
 p.setGreen(green);
 p.setBlue(blue);
```

also, take the draw and save out of the for loop

Comment: Just before `aCopy.draw()`?

Comment: In addition to setting the RGB components, as described above: **Move the `aCopy.draw();` and `aCopy.save();` out of the `for`-loop!**

Comment: A side note: Do you **have** to use this image library? If you don't have to use it: Consider a different one. `class APImage extends JFrame` makes me twitch....

Comment: @Marco13 I tried all of those things, and it still is not working.

Comment: Does the "TestGrayscale" example from the APImage documentation work for you?

Comment: @Marco13 yes it turns into grey, but it does not turn into Sepia.

Comment: In doubt, edit the question with your current code. It *should* work with the proposed changes.

Comment: @Marco13 I edited my answer , I didn't see that part ;)